# The easiest way to read uvm_object from file given by uvm_object sprint method

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

While verrifying VDU(video display unit) I faced next issue.

The VDU gets its settings from uvm_object class and I write thees settings into file using sprint method. Can you recommend me the best way to read this file back into uvm_object. In other words are there a methods inside UVM to read object properties back from the file with uvm_printer format? Or I need to implement this kind of functionality from scratch.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UVM provides no mechanism to read back settings output to a file from `sprint()`—you will have to implement this from scratch. You might consider outputting in a simpler format to make reading back easier.